# VSTO 3.0 Get/Change an excel 2007 workbook connection

Tags: connection, vsto, excel-2007

I've struggling to find a way to get and change and excel 2007 workbook connection (Menu Data -> Existing Connections -> Connections on this Workbook).It's a connection (several actually) to a SQL Server and used in a pivot table.

I've tried using **Application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections** or **Globals.ThisWorkbook.Connections** but they both return always Null..I've tried in an sheet event as well as in a custom ribbon's button event as well.

The only way left I can think of is use to code a VBA method that does the work and then invoke it in my VSTO code, but it's not very elegant is it...

Answer (score 2):

Existing connections in Excel (this works in 2007) are not active connections. You must connect using an existing connection before being able to acquire that connection (I did this manually before clicking a button that executed this code).

```
var application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
//This must be an active connection otherwise handle exceptions
// such as 'Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'
var connection = application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections["EXISTING_CONNECTION_NAME"];
var oledb = connection.OLEDBConnection;
var settings = oledb.Connection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I adjust connection string of Excel Connections. Take in account that I have only ONE connection in Workbook.

```csharp
public class WorkbookConnectionsManager
{
  public static void AdjustConnectionToSqlConnectionString(Excel.WorkbookConnection connection, String connectionString)
  {
    char[] propertiesSeparator = new char[] { ';' };
    char[] propertyValueSeparator = new char[] { '=' };

    Excel.OLEDBConnection oleDbConn = connection.OLEDBConnection;

    Dictionary<string, string> dictExcelConnStrProperties = GetConnStrDictionary(oleDbConn.Connection, propertiesSeparator, propertyValueSeparator);
    Dictionary<string, string> dictActualConnStrProperties = GetConnStrDictionary(connectionString, propertiesSeparator, propertyValueSeparator);

    string[] reggedPropertyies = new string[] { "Integrated Security", "Persist Security Info", "User ID", "Password", "Initial Catalog", "Data Source", "Workstation ID" };

    foreach (string property in reggedPropertyies)
      if (dictExcelConnStrProperties.ContainsKey(property) && dictActualConnStrProperties.ContainsKey(property)
        && null != dictActualConnStrProperties[property] && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dictActualConnStrProperties[property].ToString()))
          dictExcelConnStrProperties[property] = dictActualConnStrProperties[property];

    string connStr = GetConnStrFromDict(dictExcelConnStrProperties, propertiesSeparator[0], propertyValueSeparator[0]);

    oleDbConn.Connection = connStr;
  }

  private static string GetConnStrFromDict(Dictionary<string, string> dictConnStrProperties, char propertiesSeparator, char propertyValueSeparator)
  {
    StringBuilder connStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in dictConnStrProperties)
    {
      connStrBuilder.Append(keyValuePair.Key);
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValuePair.Value))
      {
        connStrBuilder.Append(propertyValueSeparator);
        connStrBuilder.Append(keyValuePair.Value);
      }
      connStrBuilder.Append(propertiesSeparator);
    }

    string connStr = String.Empty;
    if (connStrBuilder.Length > 1)
    {
      connStr = connStrBuilder.ToString(0, connStrBuilder.Length - 1);
    }

    return connStr;
  }

  private static Dictionary<string, string> GetConnStrDictionary(string connString, char[] propertiesSeparator, char[] propertyValueSeparator)
  {
    string[] keyAndValue;

    string[] arrayConnStrProperties = connString.Split(propertiesSeparator);
    Dictionary<string, string> dictConnStrProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string excelConnStrProperty in arrayConnStrProperties)
    {
      keyAndValue = excelConnStrProperty.Split(propertyValueSeparator);
      if (keyAndValue.Length > 1)
      {
        dictConnStrProperties.Add(keyAndValue[0], keyAndValue[1]);
      }
      else if (keyAndValue.Length > 0)
      {
        //standalone attribute
        dictConnStrProperties.Add(keyAndValue[0], String.Empty);
      }
    }

    return dictConnStrProperties;
  }



}
```

Comment: Could you consider formatting the code a bit better next time? I've done some reformatting but it'd be nice if it wasn't needed.

Comment: @KonradViltersten your edit did very little to improve the formatting of the code. I have reverted to the original.

Comment: @TomRedfern I'm going to roll-back-BACK the source to see what it looked like. Just letting you know so it doesn't appear to be an immature act of "is-too/is-not!", matie. As the code looks now (independently of what my reformatting contributes with) it's barely readable. The language isn't even recognized... Let me see what we can do about it.

Comment: @TomRedfern It's been two years ago so my memory is foggy but if I infer correctly, I never intended to reformat the post. I only added the language recognition and, possibly, some minor change. My hope was that the OP would take time to improve the rest themselves. I'm assuming it's not going to happen, hehe. Nevertheless, I say that the post **before** my addition looked even crapier then now. I agree - my change did little to decrees the crappiness. But it's a good start, at least. What's your opinion?

Comment: Agree your change represents an improvement on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where but I remember reading somewhere that the Connections collection was of limited use for writing ODBC type connections. It has several enum values for a "connection" but I'm not sure if some of those are readonly from that interface.

Regardless it should be quite easy to implement new connections and edit existing ones from VSTO. The best option would be to [use COM interop to call](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/odbccp32.SQLConfigDataSource) the [SQLConfigDataSource() function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110507/en-us) from the ODBCCP32.DLL win32 library.
Also check out [the following addin](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2005/11/29/query-editor-add-in/) which makes it easier to work with query tables in Excel.